# Nesting element inside anchor with blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How do i create this kind build with blade?

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
    <span>Charts</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
</a>
```

Is it possible with blade commands?

Comment: What about it do you want to do with Blade? Note: Blade is **not a replacement for html**

Comment: or helper of laravel?

Comment: Sums it up better... "Templating engine" is the official term ;) Anyways, you can write custom [blade macros](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade). If you need more help, you have to describe more in detail what you want / what the variable parts of your HTML are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade uses regular HTML, with curly braces for PHP blocks. Just use the `url` function in the attribute:

```html
<a href="{{ url('charts') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
    <span>Charts</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
</a>
```